# angular js, how to restrict input values to only a few numbers

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an app in angular js.
I want to create a restriction an input field to accept only 3, 6, 9, 12, 15 and so on.
It should mark it as no valid if the user writes for example an 8.

I couldn't find how to do this, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive and add your own [validator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators) that checks for multiples of 3.

See [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BWk2aCfLHXW2ax95S7Xw?p=preview)

Markup:

```
<input name="numberField" type="number" data-ng-model="model.number" data-multiple-validator="3"/>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('multipleValidator', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      if (!ngModelCtrl) {
        return;
      }

      var multiple = parseInt(attr.multipleValidator);

      if (!multiple) {
        return;
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$validators.multipleValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        return !!modelValue && modelValue%multiple === 0;
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

If it's only the numbers 3, 6, 9, 12 and 15 then you can just use [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) like so

```
<input name="numberField" type="number" data-ng-model="model.number" data-ng-pattern="/^(3|6|9|12|15)$/"/>
```

**EDIT**

If your `multiple` value is dynamic then you will have to watch for changes in your directive using the very handy [`$observe`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$observe) and re-validate when it changes. See updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CeANaFw8rdQkspaYQoNU?p=preview).

Markup:

```
<input placeholder="input" name="numberField" type="number" data-ng-model="model.number" data-multiple-validator="{{model.multiple}}"/>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('multipleValidator', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      if (!ngModelCtrl) {
        return;
      }

      ngModelCtrl.$validators.multipleValidator = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        var multiple = parseInt(attr.multipleValidator);
        if (!multiple) {
          // If there is no multiple then assume that it is valid
          return true;
        }
        return !!modelValue && modelValue%multiple === 0;
      }

      // Watch for changes to the multipleValidator attribute
      attr.$observe('multipleValidator', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        // Re-validate the input when a change is detected
        ngModelCtrl.$validate();
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Actually, @user2718281 I'm not passing 3 as a constant, but it comes from an input field. `<input ... data-multiple-validator="{{competition.teams}}"/>`, it works initially as 3 is my default **competition.teams** value, but when I change the input value at **competition.teams**, the change doesn't affect the directive. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a custom directive. Angular has built in directive called ng-pattern which lets you match the input field to your given regular expression.

Here is how i have achieved this..
CODE...

```
<html ng-app="num">
  <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="numCtrl">
    <form class="digits" name="digits">
      <input type="text" placeholder="digits here plz" name="nums" ng-model="nums" required ng-pattern="/^([0369]|[258][0369]*[147]|[147]([0369]|[147][0369]*[258])*[258]|[258][0369]*[258]([0369]|[147][0369]*[258])*[258]|[147]([0369]|[147][0369]*[258])*[147][0369]*[147]|[258][0369]*[258]([0369]|[147][0369]*[258])*[147][0369]*[147])*$/" />
      <p class="alert" ng-show="digits.nums.$error.pattern">Multiples of three only accepted.</p> 
      <br>
    </form>
      <script>
      var app = angular.module('num',[]);

app.controller('numCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.digits = {};
});
      </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Writing regex patterns in html is not a good Idea. You would end up with repeating yourself as the webapp grows big. A directive is better

Comment: You can write your regex in js files. I have written here it just for purpose of better understanding

Answer (score 0):

See this jsfiddle for a working example https://jsfiddle.net/s7mmvxq5/5/
The approach I took was to create a directive that just adds an additional `$validator` to the form field. Since the validator is just a function you can do whatever check you'd like in it.
This section of the angular docs might be of interest https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation